# this.setState on nested arrays

Tags: reactjs

EDIT**

Currently my React state looks like this.

```
this.state = {
    data: {
      groups: [[]]
    },
    preview: [[]]
}
```

The elements in groups are also arrays that hold files. I have a file change event handler that currently looks like this.

```
handlePhotoChange(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault()

    let reader = new FileReader()
    let file = e.target.files[0]

    const { data, photoPreview } = this.state
    const { groups } = data

    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            data: {
                ...data,
                groups: [...groups, [...[index], file]]
                // tried: groups: [[...index], file]
            },
            preview: [...preview, [...[index], reader.result]]
            // tried: preview: [[...index], reader.result]
        })
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

Right now this is adding another group and the photo preview is in the second group. When I did the ## tried code ## it only appended the reader.result to the preview and the groups[0] stayed null. And when i added another file it replaced the reader.result in preview[0][0]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: where do you wish to append `[file]` ? to `groups` or to an item of groups like `groups[0]` ?

Comment: to an item of groups[0].. this is because if people wish to add a new group(which will occur often) it will create a new array (groups[1]) which will hold the file (groups[1][file])

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: {
          groups: [...prevState.groups, [file]]
          // attempted - groups[index]: [...groups[index], [file]] - error
      },
      preview: [...prevState.preview, [reader.result]]
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `group: [...group, [file]]` use `Array#concat` method like `group: Array.isArray(group) ? group.concat([[file]]) : [[file]]`

And just do the same with `preview`